# How to dump local .dbm to Oracle database on Amazon RDS

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds, datapump

I have local .dbm file and I want to populate it to Oracle Database on Amazon RDS. I am using Ubuntu on my local machine. I don't seem to have a data pump utility. I cannot find option/settings in SQLDeveloper to pump my local .dbm file to the remote RDS  Oracle database.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I did import DMP files from AWS EC2 to Oracle RDS instance. It is necessary to take several steps:

```
1) Create a free instance of EC2(1 CPU core, 1G RAM, 30GD HDD ) or a paid instance with a large disk and CPU.
2) Install a free database version of the Oracle XE version on EC2 instance.
3) Copy files to the DUMP directory to Oracle XE on EC2 instance 
via the sftp protocol. 
4) Transfer files to the RDS instance.
```

Manual from Amazon [Importing Data into Oracle on Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html)

```
 5) Delete files in the DUMP directory EC2
```